# Understanding how clients handle incomplete certificate chains

Tags: tls, certificates, trust

How do clients (browser for example) handle a missing intermediate certificate?

In the following answer it is explained that they download certificates or use cached certificates: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/163660

I don't understand how this works. Where do they download them from? If they can download and cache intermediate certificates, why have an intermediate certificate store at all? Why not make it a part of the protocol, since this is considered a secure behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some certificates use the AIA (Authority Information Access) field to specify a URL from which the next certificate up in the chain can be downloaded.

For example, if you view the certificate for security.stackexchange.com, you'll see that the certificate for *.stackexchange.com is issued by Let's Encrypt, so the next certificate in the chain above the certificate for *.stackexchange.com is the certificate for Let's Encrypt Authority X3.  Sure enough, if you look in the AIA field of the certificate for *.stackexchange.com, you'll see a URL (http://cert.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/) from where the certificate for Let's Encrypt Authority X3 can be downloaded.

However, I'm not sure all browsers will read the AIA information and fetch any missing intermediate certificates from the URLs specified in the AIA.  So, for greatest reliability, it's probably best to bundle all of the certificates in the chain (including all of the intermediate certificates along with the terminating certificate for your site) in one .crt file.

For more information on AIA, see https://discussions.qualys.com/thread/12098.

Answer (score 1):

An intermediate certificate is between the CA and the site. Most of the browsers cache them and use between different sites. In case of missing certificate some users may get trust error. Therefore Authority Information Access which is a certificate extension is used. It leads you to the issuer of the certificate. and with this method it will lead you to the trust anchor. since the process is long therefore it is not included in protocol itself but cached.